# Recall jquery plugin from another jquery file

Tags: jquery, resizable

I have used a plugin to resize the columns in my html table.
I am using the plugin available at 
http://quocity.com/colresizable/
To do so I m doing

```
$(".resizable").colResizable();
```

Its working perfectly.
My table are dynamic and constantly needs to be refreshed.
The issue is that for the first time the plugin runs perfectly fine, but the moment any table is reloaded/refreshed, the resizing does not work.
Now I m looking to find a solution as to how to initialize the plugin again at each refresh of the table so taht every time the table is refreshed it again makes the columns resizable.
Please let me know if any thing is not understandable.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: When you add a table dynamically, you have to call `.colResizable()` on it, since it wasn't there when you ran the above code.

Comment: I have tried that one also but still not working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `.colResizable()` after adding the new table works for me.

```
$(function() {

    $("#addtable").click(function() {
        if ($("#sample3").length > 0) {
           $("#sample3").colResizable({
               disable: true
           });
        }
        $("#newtable").html('<table id="sample3" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><th>header</th><th>header</th><th>header</th></tr><tr><td class="left">cell</td><td>cell</td><td class="right">cell</td></tr><tr><td class="left">cell</td><td>cell</td><td class="right">cell</td></tr><tr><td class="left bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom">cell</td><td class="bottom right">cell</td></tr></table>');
        $("#sample3").colResizable({
            liveDrag: true,
            gripInnerHtml: "<div class='grip'></div>",
            draggingClass: "dragging"
        });
    });

});​
```

See [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/bmdjC/4/)

Comment: on load of table first time the resizable works fine.. in ur fiddle also.. but as soon as you again click on the "click to add table" resize functionality stops working.. thats the problem that i am facing..

Comment: You have to destroy the old resizable before you replace the table. See updated answer and fiddle.

Comment: Awesome man.. you rock.. I also tried destroying the table but was trying in a wrong way so was not successful.. Thanks a lot again..